# Knockout unable to process binding

Tags: knockout.js

How do I bind a text when it is undefined? For example name is not available:

```
<table id="recordTbl" data-bind="visible: records().length &gt; 0" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-4">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return name }"
Message: name is not defined
```

Comment: Do you mean that some of the items the `records` array does not have a `name` property?

Comment: Will there be a way to do that? Even if the object doesnt have a property (say name as in the comment), can we make anything to stop the exception? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you the `$data` binding context property which always represents the current view model to access the `name` through it:

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

With this approach KO won't throw an exception if one of the items in the `records` does not have a `name` property.

Without the `$data` the identifier named `name` is undefined. However `$data.name` is always a valid expression it just returns `undefined` if the current view model does not have a property named `name`.